# Can't see 'My Maps' in Google maps app

Tags: google-maps

According to [this](https://support.google.com/gmm/answer/6187484), I should be able to see 'My Maps' from the main google maps app in android.

1. Open the Google Maps app maps.
2. Touch the menu  >Your places.
3. Scroll down to see your maps.
4. Touch one to show it on the map.

However, when I scroll down (3), there are non of 'My Maps' shown.

Does anyone know why that might be?  Do I need to enable something?

Comment: Is location sharing off? Or location in general?

Comment: Probably just needed an update

Answer (score 0):

Download [My Maps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.m4b) and then check Google Maps again.

Comment: Thanks, but I already have the my maps application installed. (I want to use the offline google maps fucntionality)